# Подключение к SQL Server, который расположен на виртуальной машине

Tags: sql-server, datagrip

SQL Server у меня располагается на виртуальной машине, подключиться к нему пытаюсь через DataGrip на основном устройстве.

В конфигурации SQL Server включил прослушивание TCP/IP, так же там указал в IPALL прослушивание порта 1433, динамические порта отключил.

Службу SQL Server после этого так же перезагрузил и включил Агент SQL Server.

В командной строке через команду **netstat -aon** проверил, что порт прослушивается, но у него отсутсвует внешний адрес.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При подключении через SQL Server Management Studio все получается, но и запускаю я его на виртуальной машине, где и располагается SQL Server
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Я не совсем понимаю, что именно нужно указывать в параметрах **Host, Instance** в DataGrip, а так же способ аутентификации**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал в Host указать IP адрес, полученный через командную строку командой **ipconfig** и порт 1433 с использованием аутентификации User&Password, но не получилось
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пользователя я добавил через SQL Server Management Studio
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если пишет, что ошибка аутентификации, значит до сервера достучались и проверили логин-пароль. Когда сервер не доступен, то пишет именно это.

Comment: @teran , тогда тем более не понимаю в чем проблема, СОздавал нескольких пользователей , но со всеми такая ошибка. Не думаю что я столько раз неправильно ввел логин-пароль

Comment: Должно помочь: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/db-tutorial-connecting-to-ms-sql-server.html#connect-by-using-windows-domain-authentication-macos-and-linux